# SQL Query to Identify latest inactive combinations while leaving active combinations

Tags: mysql

**Note:** By `combination`, I'll refer to `svc_id` & `loc_id`

I'm interested in finding a latest unique set of `combination` having `status` set as zero, if a `combination` had `status` set as zero, but later on it was again set as 1, then that `combination` should be ignored!

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `activity_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prj_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `svc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `loc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`id`, `prj_id`, `svc_id`, `loc_id`, `status`, `created_by`, `created_at`, `deleted_by`, `deleted_at`) VALUES
(1, 7751, 7825, 5321, 1, 1, '2018-02-26 06:16:52', NULL, NULL),
(2, 7751, 7821, 5321, 0, 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:05', 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:33'),
(3, 7751, 7821, 5323, 1, 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:05', NULL, NULL),
(4, 7751, 7825, 5324, 0, 1, '2018-02-26 06:16:52', 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:33'),
(5, 7751, 7825, 5325, 1, 1, '2018-02-26 06:16:52', NULL, NULL),
(6, 7751, 7825, 5326, 0, 1, '2018-02-26 06:16:52', 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:33'),
(7, 7751, 7821, 5327, 0, 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:05', 1, '2018-02-26 06:17:33'),
(8, 7751, 7825, 5326, 1, 1, '2018-02-26 06:16:52', NULL, NULL);
```

---

**Query 1**: Showing all results

```
SELECT * FROM `activity_log`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f691e7/3)**:

```
| id | prj_id | svc_id | loc_id | status | created_by |           created_at | deleted_by |           deleted_at |
|----|--------|--------|--------|--------|------------|----------------------|------------|----------------------|
|  1 |   7751 |   7825 |   5321 |   true |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |     (null) |               (null) |
|  2 |   7751 |   7821 |   5321 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  3 |   7751 |   7821 |   5323 |   true |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |     (null) |               (null) |
|  4 |   7751 |   7825 |   5324 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  5 |   7751 |   7825 |   5325 |   true |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |     (null) |               (null) |
|  6 |   7751 |   7825 |   5326 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  7 |   7751 |   7821 |   5327 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  8 |   7751 |   7825 |   5326 |   true |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |     (null) |               (null) |
```

---

**Query 2**: Showing offline combinations

```
SELECT * FROM `activity_log` WHERE `status` = 0 GROUP BY `svc_id`, `loc_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f691e7/3)**:

```
| id | prj_id | svc_id | loc_id | status | created_by |           created_at | deleted_by |           deleted_at |
|----|--------|--------|--------|--------|------------|----------------------|------------|----------------------|
|  7 |   7751 |   7821 |   5327 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  6 |   7751 |   7825 |   5326 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  4 |   7751 |   7825 |   5324 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  2 |   7751 |   7821 |   5321 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
```

**Expected Results:** ID 6 should be excluded as it's `combination` is already activated in ID 8

```
| id | prj_id | svc_id | loc_id | status | created_by |           created_at | deleted_by |           deleted_at |
|----|--------|--------|--------|--------|------------|----------------------|------------|----------------------|
|  7 |   7751 |   7821 |   5327 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  4 |   7751 |   7825 |   5324 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:16:52Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
|  2 |   7751 |   7821 |   5321 |  false |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:05Z |          1 | 2018-02-26T06:17:33Z |
```

---

**[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f691e7/3)**

Comment: combination of what?

Comment: @Strawberry I've already Mentioned By combination, I'll refer to `svc_id` & `loc_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `activity_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `svc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `loc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`id`, `svc_id`, `loc_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1,  7825, 5321, 1),
(2,  7821, 5321, 0),
(3,  7821, 5323, 1),
(4,  7825, 5324, 0),
(5,  7825, 5325, 1),
(6,  7825, 5326, 0),
(7,  7821, 5327, 0),
(8,  7825, 5326, 1);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM activity_log a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id FROM activity_log GROUP BY svc_id,loc_id) b 
    ON b.id = a.id 
 WHERE a.status = 0;
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | svc_id | loc_id | status |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  2 |   7821 |   5321 |      0 |
|  4 |   7825 |   5324 |      0 |
|  7 |   7821 |   5327 |      0 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

EDIT: To demonstrate the fallacy of the cdaiga's solution, consider this simplified example...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS activity_log;

CREATE TABLE `activity_log` 
(`id` int(11) NOT NULL
,`svc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
,`loc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
,`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
, INDEX(loc_id,svc_id)
);

INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`id`, `svc_id`, `loc_id`, `status`) VALUES
( 1, 5, 1, 1),
( 2, 1, 1, 0),
( 3, 1, 3, 1),
( 4, 5, 4, 0),
( 5, 5, 5, 1),
( 6, 5, 6, 0),
( 7, 1, 7, 0),
( 8, 5, 6, 1),
( 9, 5, 1, 0),
(10, 5, 1, 1),
(11, 1, 1, 0);
```

The correct answer is given by the following:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM activity_log a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id FROM activity_log GROUP BY svc_id,loc_id) b 
    ON b.id = a.id 
 WHERE a.status = 0;

+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | svc_id | loc_id | status |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  4 |      5 |      4 |      0 |
|  7 |      1 |      7 |      0 |
| 11 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

However, cdaiga's answer may give an erroneous result, as follows:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM `activity_log` A
WHERE A.`status` = 0 AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT null
            FROM `activity_log` B
            WHERE A.`svc_id`=B.`svc_id` AND  A.`loc_id`=B.`loc_id`
            AND B.`status`=1)
GROUP BY `svc_id`, `loc_id`
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | svc_id | loc_id | status |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  7 |      1 |      7 |      0 |
|  4 |      5 |      4 |      0 |
|  2 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you review @cdaiga's answer .. and guide me which one is better?

Comment: Mine's better, obviously :-)

Comment: I know .. but how? :) Need a bit explanation as both queries are giving the same result!

Comment: The other answer may give a correct answer, but it cannot be guaranteed

Comment: Again how? .. need to choose one!

Comment: The concept is based on the `combination` .. now once it is reactivated, the result shouldn't show it ... i've tested both queries in multiple scenarios, and both are working fine .. now the elephant in the room is .. which one is more efficient?

Comment: The alternative solution is undocumented, and the result it provides is indeterminate. It *may* return the correct answer, but this is down to luck (a quirk of the way the database internals organise data) rather than design.

Comment: I see now, thanks for the demo @Strawberry. I voted up your answer.

Comment: @cdaiga - this only goes half way to explaining what's wrong with your query. The deeper issue is harder to demonstrate, but if I think of a way, I'll update my answer again.